# Who has linked the analysis of modernism or post modernism to Lacan's four discourses?

Tags: reference-request, postmodernism, lacan, literary-theory, modernism

Who has linked the analysis of modernism or post modernism to Lacan's [four discourses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_discourses)?

I mean obviously there's some kinda link between the master's discourse and at least some forms of modernism. I'm asking because I want to make sense of why post modern literary texts seem to lack, I suppose emotional, depth, in terms of their performative, lyric, aspects.

Comment: That seems overly broad a call.  If it applied to discourse, would it not then apply to all of our media, which are not necessarily less deep emotionally?  Or are you talking about a specific vertical of texts?  If anything, I think you see a lack of integration between the discourses, but not a deterioration of them.

Comment: I don't think i can answer here, but you can look at the similarities between the Victorian era and the present to see that having these four forces pull apart and go wild is not linked directly to postmodernism -- (hysterical) resurgence of supernaturalism and conspiracy theories (especially about technology and science), (academic) excessive elevation of specific professions (then medicine, now computing) and abandonment of respect for others,  (master) decoupling of the logic of financial risk from its effects, (analyst) psychologism/addictionology and 'snowflakes' (eccentrics).